# Rails system test w/ Capybara RackTest raises ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a typical Rails model form with a file attachment selector allowing multiple attachments. It works fine in development, but during a system test, raises an `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` exception.

- Rails 7.0.2.2
- capybara 3.36.0
- rack-test 1.1.0

The model `has_many_attached :photos`.

The form is using `form_with` and `multipart: true`.

The HTML source looks correct.

In development, manually using the form with 0 or any file attachments works as expected.

In my system test, I am using the `rack_test` driver.

```
test "creating a quote request" do
  visit new_quote_request_path
  fill_in "First name", with: 'FAKE FIRST'
  # ...
  click_on "Submit"
  assert_text "Success"
end
```

In the controller, my canonical param-permitting method looks like:

```
def quote_request_params
  params.require(:quote_request).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email,
    :phone_number, :shipping, :promo_code, :description, :item_type_id, :brand_id,
    photos: [])
end
```

My controller `create` method is typical...

```
def create
  @quote_request = QuoteRequest.new(quote_request_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  # ...
```

In the system test, the call of `QuoteRequest.new(quote_request_params)` raises an `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` exception.

With a breakpoint in place, I can see that the `quote_request_params` looks like:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"FAKE FIRST",
"last_name"=>"FAKE LAST", "email"=>"fake@fake.com", 
"phone_number"=>"5415555555", "shipping"=>"1", "promo_code"=>"", 
"description"=>"Fake quote request description.", 
"item_type_id"=>"980190962", "brand_id"=>"980190962",
"photos"=>[
  "",
  "#<Capybara::RackTest::Form::NilUploadedFile:0x000000010dae35b8>"
]} permitted: true>
```

And it seems Capybara is doing its default behavior of attaching a 'nil file' for the multipart form.

Why is the test raising an `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` exception?

Comment: That photos parameter looks like you're actually getting a string (the result of `Object#to_s`) and not an instance of `Capybara::RackTest::Form::NilUploadedFile`. Something weird is going on.

Comment: Ah, thanks @max I will dig into this further.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and have opened an issue: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Rails 7 and rack-test. It can temporarily be solved by putting the following in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```rb
config.active_storage.multiple_file_field_include_hidden = false
```

Refer to the [rack-test issue](https://github.com/rack/rack-test/pull/278) for more details.